# Using the open graph API, is there a way to determine which friends of a user have an @facebook.com email address setup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api

The title basically sums it up.  After fetching the list of friends for a facebook-connected user, I'm looking for a way to determine if the friend is using the new messaging system with the @facebook.com email.  I'm using the javascript SDK.

Along the same lines, is there a way to pre-populate the To: list with Facebook's new Send button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not providing it Yet as you can see the user profile info they are providing [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) 
And no for now you can't send message to user/user friends through API. Its included in there road map they will provide the feature to send message to user's inbox in upcoming days.
But There can be a manual method by calling a URL like this http://www.facebook.com/inbox/?compose&id=516888778
I know that is something you don't wanna use but this is all you can do right now.

Comment: Thanks.  Why can;t I use the manual method?  Is there anyway I can pre-populate the message textbox?  If I can, then that's pretty much all I need!

Comment: Because they have not added the functions that allow user to send message directly yet. It is included in there road map they will provide it soon. You can prefill messages by adding a parameter msg_prefill http://www.facebook.com/messages/516888778?msg_prefill=message

Comment: @mani--using this technique, do you know if there is anyway to send the message to multiple friends at once? Thanks...

Comment: No it was in previous rest API but not available now.

Answer (score 3):

These FQL tables might be useful:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/unified_message/

check other **unified_** tables here:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql

Check their note:

> We are in the process of making the
>   new messages system available to all
>   users, at which point this table will
>   replace the existing message table. We
>   are providing early access to this API
>   for **registered developer accounts only**
>   until the new messaging system is
>   broadly available. You should use the
>   message table for production
>   applications at the current time.

It says for registered developer accounts only and is in BETA mode. But you may want to query against this table to check which one got his new inbox implemented, else the table will return null or no data. However, using this needs **read_mailbox** permission.

If you will notice the @facebook.com email of users are using their usernames (**username@facebook.com**). If you are able to get the usernames of the currently-logged-in user's friends, then you may want to send each one an email and check which did not send through.

Answer (score 2):

No. You can get the user's own e-mail address ([with the `email` permission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/)), but not those of hir friends. This is By Design, and a Good Thing (even if my friends are eager to give out *their* data, they have no business to hand out *mine*)

Comment: I'm not asking about their email address that's registered with their facebook account.  I'm referring to the new facebook messaging which gives users an @facebook.com email.  You can get the user's friend's usernames, so their email would be username@facebook.com.  Only caveat is that all users have not yet moved to new messaging platform.

Comment: @Prabhu: The answer is still "no", for the exact same reasons I have outlined. ("Oh, so there *is* a functional e-mail address myfriend1@facebook.com and myfriend2@facebook.com, whereas myfriend3@facebook.com is not functional? Wonderful, thank you for this info, which is now effectively public.") I'm not implying any evil intent on *your* part; I'm just saying that this would be trivial to abuse by anyone with a FB app, thus it's not available.

Comment: Facebook is making it public, not me :-) For more info, see http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=19031

Comment: Also, I think it would not be abuse, if emails are sent to friend@facebook.com from the user's own email address, and with the user's consent--effectively it's like the user simply sending his/her friend an email.

Answer (score 1):

They do use a certain format, which is either the FaceBook ID, or the FaceBook moniker they setup for themselves.  That won't let you check anything, but it's a step in that direction.  There may be a permission you can request which will let you interact with a person's friends via messaging, like with sending messages and wall posts, but I can't say.

Also, if you request a person's email, they can opt out, or offer a FB proxy address, so it's not a guarantee.

Comment: Any idea how I can message a user's friend any other way?  The new facebook Send button is available, but I'm wondering if there's a way to send a message to a specific user given their username...